# AppMaker Drive.Files.list query for properties

Tags: google-app-maker

`function searchDrive(teamDriveId) {
  var args = {
    corpora: 'teamDrive',
    includeTeamDriveItems: true,
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
    q: "properties has { key = 'source' and value = 'internet' }"
  };
  return Drive.Files.list(args).items;`

results in: GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid query at searchDrive (ServerScript:9)

I have ran the same query in the API Explorer and received successful results. I have ran other queries (`mimeType='image/jpeg'`) using the Drive.Files.list API in AppMaker and received successful results.

Has anyone queried 'properties' using this API? Does anyone have any insights into what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a proper query you need to include the visibility property; hence it should be:

```
function searchDrive(teamDriveId) {
  var args = {
    corpora: 'teamDrive',
    includeTeamDriveItems: true,
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
    q: "properties has { key = 'source' and value = 'internet' and visibility='PRIVATE' }"
  };
  return Drive.Files.list(args).items;
}
```

Please note the `visibility='PRIVATE'` part. Possible values are `PRIVATE and PUBLIC` according to [**the documentation**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/properties).

Comment: What is odd is that the documentation specifically states: `Allowed values are PRIVATE and PUBLIC. (Default: PRIVATE)`

Comment: @303Brad I know right! I'm positive its a bug but pretty sure Google won't fix it. At this point, I'm used to deal with this kind of issues. Google does this all the time!